# Get date and time form postgresql

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I use a postgresql table and I have to store automatically time and date after each new insertion

```
CREATE TABLE dns_table
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  name_name character varying(15) NOT NULL,
  city text,
  query_time timestamp without time zone DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0) ;,
  CONSTRAINT dns_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

the format of query_time column is : 2014-04-30 11:04:49, I'm wondering if there is a way to have this format : 2014-04-30 11:04 (without second)

thank you a lot :)

Comment: A `timestamp` does not have "a format". A format is only applied when you _display_ the value. The storage on disk is completely independent from that. Formatting is always done by the program that displays the value. Usually each SQL client has some kind of way to configure the _default format_ that is applied when displaying such a value. Check the documentation of your SQL tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the function [date_trunc()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT):

```
SELECT date_trunc('minute', NOW());
```

Edit:
[to_char()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) could be the function you're looking for, just check it.

```
SELECT to_char(NOW(), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI');
```

Comment: Thak you Frank,
SELECT to_char(NOW(), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'); it's exactly what I want but how to use it in table creation ?

Comment: Don't use it when the table is created, only when you SELECT the data you need.